# How to pass allowDiskUse= true while using an aggregate function in api "POST"

Tags: post, postman, aggregate

I am trying to make an aggregate call using post method .My body(json) looks like this:

```
{
   "aggregate":[
      {
         "$group":{
            "_id":{
               "mac_address":"$mac",
               "address":"$ip"
            },
            "hostnames":{
               "$addToSet":"$hostname"
            },
            "interfaces":{
               "$addToSet":"$interfaceName"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$project":{
            "_id":0,
            "mac_address":"$_id.mac_address",
            "address":"$_id.address",
            "hostnames":"$hostnames",
            "interfaces":"$interfaces"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Since the source data has a lot of documents (in lakhs) to process, i am getting the below error:
Command failed with error 16945 (Location16945): 'Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.' on server.

I know how to pass allowDiskUse property in mongo-db tools such as Robo 3t , but not able to do the same in postman. Need help!

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh*. A lot of people aren't going to understand what *in lakhs* means.

Answer (score 0):

My answer depends on the use-case.
It works with the assumption that you have to export data, and it is not for the application code. This should work without `allowDiskUse` property as well.

1. Run a first aggregation to export the possible combinations to a temp collection. The code will look like this

```
db.<name>.aggregate([
{$match: {...}},
{$group: {...}},
{$project: {...}},
{$out: "temp_collection_1"}
])
```

2. run the second aggregation on the temp collection, and perform other operations like lookup, sort, etc. and output to another temp collection

```
db.temp_collection_1.aggregate([
{$match: {}},
{$lookup: {...}},
{$sort: {...}},
{$out: "temp_collection_2"}
])
```

3. use mongoexport to dump entire `temp_collection_2` collection
4. drop the temp collections